# Crontab on week numbers

Tags: shell, cron

I would like to set a cronjob on certain week numbers. The reason for that, I have a script that should run once a day except of week number 8 and 9. There it should run twice a day.

How can I set a cronjob based on week numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Cron doesn't offer that level of scheduling flexibility, so you have to make your script smarter.

Make your cron job run twice a day, leaving some log file or other artifact that shows it has run. Then have it check whether it's already run that day, and finally also check the week number to see if it's OK for it to run the second time.

Comment: +1 on the "make the script smarter". As a simpler alternative to modifying the script to handle the "did I already run today?" situation you could define two separate cron jobs and pass a "this is the second time today" option to the script on the later run.

Comment: @ottomeister I agree, that's a better idea, particularly since it doesn't rely on an artifact surviving between runs of the script.